# onPreviewFrame not being called

Tags: java, android, camera

I have the following method to open the camera facing the user:

```
    CameraOperations.java

    private Parameters parameters = null;
    private Camera cam = null;
    private Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    private static int camNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    public Camera toggleFaceCamera(){

        if(cam == null){
            for(int counter = 0; counter < camNumber; counter++){
                Camera.getCameraInfo(counter, cameraInfo);
                if(cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT){
                    try{
                        cam = Camera.open(counter);
                        parameters = cam.getParameters();
                        parameters.setPreviewFormat(16);
                        return cam;
                    }catch(RuntimeException e){return null;}
                }
            }
        }else{cam.release();}

        return null;

    }

    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam){
            Debug.out("teste");
        }
```

**Which is called likewise:**

```
MainActivity.java

surface = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
            holder = surface.getHolder();

            Camera cam = CameraOperations.toggleFaceCamera();

            try{
                cam.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                //cam.setPreviewCallback(CameraOperations.());
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            cam.startPreview();
```

**and all this works just fine, the camera is displayed correctly**

Unfortunately onPreviewFrame is not being called. I've tried several things using setPreviewCallback and setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer but honestly I'm not understanding why this won't work since onPreviewFrame should be called with the display of frames... I've read the documentation but I feel a little misguided about how this works, if anyone could make me understand it clearly I would be much thankful! (example I tried)

```
(...)
           try{
                        cam = Camera.open(counter);
                        parameters = cam.getParameters();
                        parameters.setPreviewFormat(16);
                        cam.setPreviewCallback(onPreviewFrame);   <---- doens't recognize argument
                        return cam;
                    }catch(RuntimeException e){return null;}
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the call commands to use

```
cam.setPreviewCallback(this);
```

from inside the **CameraOperations** class.

To have the preview callbacks, you must call

```
cam.startPreview();
```

If you want your parameters to be used (e.g. after changing the preview format), you need

```
cam.setParameters(parameters);
```

Normally, you want to set parameters *before* you `startPreview()`.

Comment: I called `cam.startPreview();` in mainactivity.java, and it works, the frames are displayed correctly... When I call `cam.setPreviewCallback(this);` inside togglefacecamera as in the example it shows `The method setPreviewCallback(Camera.PreviewCallback) in the type Camera is not applicable for the arguments (CameraOperations)`. If I call `setPreviewCallback(onPreviewFrame)` instead I get "onPreviewFrame couldn't be resolved into a variable". Could you tell me exactly where I should call it and how please?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by：

moving the .setPreviewCallback behind the .startPreview.

```
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        mCamera.setPreviewCallback(previewCallback);
```